# android - ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(int, View, ViewGroup, int) line: 355 NullPointerException

Tags: android

I'm setting an ArrayAdapter and I get the following error:

```
 Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException)) 
ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(int, View, ViewGroup, int) line: 355    
ArrayAdapter.getView(int, View, ViewGroup) line: 323    
ListView(AbsListView).obtainView(int, boolean[]) line: 1294 
ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(int, int, int, int, int) line: 1198
```

My symptomremedyActivity.java looks like:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.symptomremedy);
    ListView remedyList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_SymptomRemedy);
    remedyList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu_item, remedyArray);
    remedyList.setAdapter(adapt);
```

and my symptomremedy.xml layout looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/Button_BACK"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_button_height"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Button_BACK"
android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView_MenuHeader"
android:textSize="@dimen/menu_button_text_size"
android:text="@string/back"></Button>

<ListView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ListView_SymptomRemedy"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/menu_white"
        android:divider="@drawable/straight_divider"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/textured"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and menu_item.xml layout looks like:

```
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:textSize="@dimen/menu_item_size"
android:text="test string"
android:textColor="@color/menu_black"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />
```

I've done something similar in other Activities with no problems, so I can't figure out why there is a problem here.  All of the fields involved are non-null, i.e. remedyArray, etc.  Anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the way I was creating the array for the ArrayAdapter.  Previously the code I had was:

```
String remedyArray[] = new String[30];
```

When I changed the code to:

```
    String remedyArray[] = new String[30];
    for ( int i = 0; i< 30; i++){
            remedyArray[i] = "";
    }
```

everything worked.  I don't completely understand why, but it appeared that initializing the array with values did the trick.  I guess one of the uniquenesses of Java is that when an array is created, the entries contain null, and I think it was those null values that were causing the problem.

Comment: I had this problem too. Thanks for solving it out loud here!

Comment: I was facing same issue. I searched lot for this, and found this after toooooo much trial on code..... Very much thankful for this.

Answer (score 8):

The NullPointerException in

```
ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource
```

suggests that the problem is coming from

```
R.layout.menu_item
```

If this file exists under /res/layout/, check that it's registered in R.java

Also, are you using a custom ArrayAdapter? If so, please update the question with the code.

If you are not using a custom ArrayAdapter, try adding an identifier to the TextView in menu_item. If you are not overriding getView, Android will try to fill a TextView in the resourceId (menu_item.xml) with the data in *remedyList*. I've never done this, but you may need to specify the TextView id by using this constructor:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

Check [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) constructors.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the custom item layout and the dropdown item layout weren't using the same Id for the main textview; basically because I wanted to create a custom item, but maintain the default dropdown item.

the id in textViewResourceId must be the same for both views.

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

Creating a custom dropdown item with the same textview id solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for digging up this question but I came across the issue today and I understood why this happens.

If you statically allocate some space for a newly created array (ie. `String[] array = new String[80]`) you have to make sure that you fill all the 81 places of the array. Because if you do not they will be filled with `null` values thus causing the `NullPointerException`.

When you filled the array with empty strings you basically found a work-around over this.