# How do I get this simple note taking app to work?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I am new to android programming and I can't seem to find the problem with the following program:

Main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_list_layout,
                listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_insert:

            createReminder();
            return true;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;

    private void createReminder() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReminderEditActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent intent) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            listItems.add(intent.getStringExtra("reminder_text"));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

}
```

Secondary class:

```
public class ReminderEditActivity extends Activity {

    EditText editText;

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {

        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.reminder_edit);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }

    public void onPostButtonClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("text", editText.getText().toString());
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

So the program starts up fine, when I click on the add button, I'm taken to the second page
with a text field and button as expected. When I fill in the field and click the button, the program crashes. I'm given a null pointer exception but it doesn't point to anywhere in my code, just to the array adapter code(more specifically ArrayAdapter.java:394). I have some programming experience but I new to debugging android projects. Any direction would be appreciated.

Stack Trace:

```
12-23 18:08:37.881: D/dalvikvm(1654): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 71K, 5% free 2989K/3136K, paused 40ms, total 43ms
12-23 18:08:37.891: I/dalvikvm-heap(1654): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.596MB for 635812-byte allocation
12-23 18:08:37.951: D/dalvikvm(1654): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 5% free 3606K/3760K, paused 56ms, total 56ms
12-23 18:08:38.251: D/gralloc_goldfish(1654): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-23 18:09:07.971: I/Choreographer(1654): Skipped 82 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-23 18:09:08.151: I/Choreographer(1654): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-23 18:09:10.231: I/Choreographer(1654): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-23 18:09:17.151: D/AndroidRuntime(1654): Shutting down VM
12-23 18:09:17.151: W/dalvikvm(1654): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a19b90)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654): Process: food.start.thefoodapp, PID: 1654
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2289)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1914)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1111)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1293)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-23 18:09:17.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 18:09:21.121: I/Process(1654): Sending signal. PID: 1654 SIG: 9
```

Here is my_list_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/identView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</TextView>
```

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer ([android - ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(int, View, ViewGroup, int) line: 355 NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544738/android-arrayadapter-createviewfromresourceint-view-viewgroup-int-line-3)).

It likely has to do with your my_list_layout and how the Adapter is trying to populate the given String values into it. In particular, the ArrayAdapter documentation states that:

> By default this class expects that the provided resource id references
>   a single TextView

If this isn't the desired behaviour, then modify your layout or create a subclass of ArrayAdapter and override the getView() method.

ArrayAdapter docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Edit: As for more details on what the layout or extending ArrayAdapter looks like, the layout should look something like this, with the TextView at the root of the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

On the other hand, if you want to extend ArrayAdapter (which is very common), you can take a look on Google for a number of tutorials, or take a look at section 3.2 in this tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

All the best!

Comment: could you elaborate on how I would modify my layout or what the subclass of ArrayAdapter should look like?